# Azure Teams Bot not responding after a few minuets

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

We developed a bot for teams using Azure Bot Service and C#. It's working well in my local using Bot Framework Emulator, but in Teams, it's been working for some time and stopped responding. Suppose I uninstall and install it, it works well and repeats the same issue. Am I missing anything?

I wrote all my code in one dialog which is MainDialog.cs.

Comment: There is a significant difference between emulating a bot on a local computer and running in the cloud. I was getting behavior similar to yours when my bot was misconfigured. In my case, it was about using a service and an OAuth connection that was incorrectly configured in the cloud. Bots with simple dialogs never crash, please clarify your question regarding the code and dialogs so that we can try to answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please reverify if you have configured your bot correctly?

Comment: If your bot starts failing, could you please navigate to Azure Bot Teams channel and check if there is any error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The following modifications are required to solve the issue. As the code was not shared, the solution contains sample code which worked in testing.

**Steps to be performed:**

- Downgrade .Net version
- Downgrade SDK version to 3.14 as it is having issue after that version

`sealed class BotJwtRefreshWorker : IDisposable`
`{`

`CancellationTokenSource _Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();`

```
    public BotJwtRefreshWorker()
    {
        var appID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppId"];
        var appPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MicrosoftAppPassword"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(appPassword))
        {
            var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(appID, appPassword);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                async () =>
                {
                    var ct = _Cts.Token;
                    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // GetTokenAsync method internally calls RefreshAndStoreToken, meaning that the token will automatically be cached at this point and you don’t need to do anything else – the bot will always have a valid token.
                            await credentials.GetTokenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                         }
                         catch (Exception ex)
                         {
                             Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
                         }
                         await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
                     }
                 },
                 TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

This makes the waiting time less or null according to the values mentioned.